# How to make a string circular in java

Tags: java, string, substring

For example, i have a string:
 "abcdefgh"

and i want it to output that one sting into three letter substrings so it becomes:

```
"abc"
"bcd"
"cde"
"def"
"efg"
"fgh"
"gha"
"hab"
```

I currently have the code:

```
      for (*length of string*){
      (str.substring(i,i+2));
```

This is with I being the counter of the string.

That being said, how will i make it so that it treats the string as circular so that i can get the sub strings "GHA" and "HAB"?

Thanks

Comment: Take the first 8 substrings from twice the string "abcdefghabcdefgh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with:

```
int length = 3;
String input = "abcdefgh";
String circural = input + input.substring(0, length - 1);

for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
    String part = circural.substring(i, i + length);
    System.out.println(part);
}
```

Output:

```
abc
bcd
cde
def
efg
fgh
gha
hab
```

Comment: why not `input + input` instead of `input + input.substring(0, length)`? `circural` will be a new string anyway, won't it?

Comment: @Joffrey Because we do not need `abcdefghabcdefgh`, just `abcdefghab`

Comment: Ok I hadn't seen you had parametrized 2, and `length` was in fact the substring length, not the input length ;)